# TypeError: values.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, javascript-objects

I am trying to map the `object` but in meantime it gives me the following error: `TypeError: values.map is not a function`. I am new to React development.

I am using this method in Redux `method`

**Code**

```
export function createEvent(values) {
  let modifyValue = values.map(newValue => {
    return {
      subject: newValue.id,
      taskType: newValue.tasktype,
      time: newValue.time,
      date: newValue.date,
      notes: newValue.notes,
      createdAt: newValue.createdAt,
      updatedAt: newValue.updatedAt,
      deletedAt: newValue.deletedAt,
      userId: newValue.userId,
      customerId: localStorage.getItem("customerValue"),
      start: newValue.start,
      end: newValue.end
    };
  });
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .post("api/diary/create", modifyValue)

      .then(response => {
        return dispatch({ type: SET_DIARY_TASK_SUCCESS, data: response });
      })

      .catch((xhr, status, err) => {
        return dispatch({ type: SET_DIARY_TASK_FAILURE, data: xhr });
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Did you check what data are coming in values before `map` ?

Comment: What is `values`, where does it come from?

Comment: @NeelRathod it object

Comment: @Cristy It object

Comment: when I console or store `values` in localstorage it give me result `[object object]`

Comment: Try this `Array.isArray(values)`

Comment: @NeelRathod error `Array.isArray(...).map is not a function`

Comment: Just put this `Array.isArray(values)`

Comment: In map function ?

Comment: No just before starting at function

Comment: `function createEvent(values) { const isArray = Array.isArray (values); console.log(isArray); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.prototype.map() is using to iterate through array and create new array. If values is a flat object access to it properties explicitly with:

```
values.propertyName
```

Your case:

```
let modifyValue = {
      subject: values.id,
      taskType: values.tasktype,
      time: values.time,
      date: values.date,
      notes: values.notes,
      createdAt: values.createdAt,
      updatedAt: values.updatedAt,
      deletedAt: values.deletedAt,
      userId: values.userId,
      customerId: localStorage.getItem("customerValue"),
      start: values.start,
      end: values.end
    };
```

Comment: @Jackobec  could you please see my example and modify it with correct version ?

Comment: No problem, see the code above

Comment: means, I don't want to use map ?

Comment: If you have only one object in values, you don't need .map()

Comment: I am getting values but data is not send to server . I am getting error `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: Could you put next code: 
console.log(JSON.stringify(values));

Next line after export function createEvent(values) {
And write please console output here in comments

Comment: {"slots":["2019-08-27T04:00:00.000Z","2019-08-27T04:30:00.000Z"],"start":"2019-08-27T04:00:00.000Z","end":"2019-08-27T04:30:00.000Z","resourceId":null,"action":"click","box":{"x":538,"y":391,"clientX":538,"clientY":275},"subject":"fasdf","taskType":"meeting","time":"9:00 am","date":"2019-08-27T04:00:00.000Z","notes":"fasdfdf","userId":"61"}

Comment: can you please check it

Comment: I'd checked. There are some mistakes: values.tasktype is incorrect, correct is values.taskType; values.createdAt, values.updatedAt, values.deletedAt are not present in values. They will be undefined in the modifyValue. I think that it is a reason of server error after send data.

Comment: Solved, Thank You so much . You are great !!

Comment: Any time)))))))

Answer (score 2):

Objects don't have .map method.

You can create an array with `Object.keys` or `Object.values` then map it.

```js
const obj = {
  1: "first value",
  2: "second value",
  3: "third value"
}

Object.keys(obj).map((el) => {
  console.log(el);
})

Object.values(obj).map((el) => {
  console.log(el);
})
```

Comment: Error is gone but I am object value is not coming . it give me null value

Comment: In that case you first need to check existency of values ( `if(values) { ...} else  { ...Error Handler }`)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `.map()` method work on `array`, In your case you first need to check `values` are in array(`[]`) form with `Array.isArray(values)`, If it's result `true` it means it's in array form then you can use `.map()` or if it's `false` then make sure calling function pass it in array form.